# When i submit text it wont leave text-area

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a wierd problem! I am currently posting data with Ajax, and it works fine, it posts the data and update as it should. The problem im having tho is, when i press the button "submit" in the textarea in the modal, that posts the new instructions, the text wont leave the textarea, like a post text should, but it does the posts the values via ajax as i want..

It's the textarea inside the modal with the name instructions that im wondering about. So what im wondering is why the text wont go away when it's posted. The Ajax works as it should..What's wrong?

Here is my first html

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="headlineBox">
            <h2 class="headlineTodo text-light"> ToDo list Application PHP and Mysql Database</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center createMargin"> 
    
    <form method="post" action=" " class="form-inline">
       
        <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2">Todo</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            </div>
                <input type="text" name="toDo"  class="form-control" id="todoTask" placeholder="Add things to do">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div  class="row justify-content-center">
       <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>ToDo task</th>
                <th>Add instructions</th>
                <th>time Created</th>
                <th>Delete task</th>
            </tr>
```

First php code

```
  <?php 
            $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM todo");
            $todo = $stmt->fetchAll();

            // skapa en tabell 
            foreach($todo as $task) {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo '<td><label class="toDoCheckBox">';
                    echo "<td>".$task['toDo']."</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='#testmodal'class='connect_modal' data-toggle ='modal' data-target='#testmodal' data-title ='".$task['toDo']."' data-id='".$task['id']."'>Add</a></td>";
                    echo "<td>".date("Y-m-d",$task['timestamp'])."</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='addToDo.php?id=".$task['id']."'>Ta bort</a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";      
            }
        ?>
</table> // end table
</div>
```

```html
 <div class="modal fade" id="testmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Todo instructions for</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="confirmUpdate"></div>
            <div class="listInstructions">
            <table id="showInstructions">
            <tr>
                <th>Instructions</th>
            </tr>
            <!--<td><div id="showInstructions"></div></td>-->    

            </table>
            <button id="closeInstruction" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <textarea name="instructions" class="form-control" id="instructionsText" style="min-width: 100%;"></textarea> 
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="showList">Show instructions</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submitInstructions">Save changes</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#showList").click(function(){
            $(".listInstructions").show();
           }); 

           $("#closeInstruction").click(function(){
               $(".listInstructions").hide();
           });

        var instructionsModal = $('#testmodal'), // The modal 
            showInstructions = $('#showInstructions'), // The Div where we want to show the instructions
            instructionsText = $('#instructionsText'), // ID to the textarea 
            submitInstructions = $('#submitInstructions'),// Button in the Text area
            ModalLabel = $('#ModalLabel');
        

        instructionsModal.on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var target = $(e.relatedTarget),
                todoId = target.data('id'),
                taskName = target.data('title'); // The uniqe id to todo instruction column
            submitInstructions.attr('data-id', todoId); // Button ID
            ModalLabel.html("#ID " + todoId + " " + taskName); 
            $('#modalElement').data('modal', null);
            $.ajax({
                url:"fetchTodoDetails.php",
                method: "POST",
                data:{todoId:todoId, status:"select"},
                dataType:"JSON",
                success:function(data)
                {   
                    var st = "";
                    $.each(data, function(index){
                    st += "<tr><td>"+data[index]+"</td>";
                    });
                    $("#showInstructions").html(st);
                    //showInstructions.html(data);
                }
            })
        });

        submitInstructions.on('click', function (e) {
            var todoId = submitInstructions.attr('data-id'),
                newInstruction = instructionsText.val();
                console.log(todoId);
            $.ajax({
                url:"fetchTodoDetails.php",
                method: "POST",
                data:{todoId:todoId, status:"update", newInstruction:newInstruction},
                dataType:"JSON",
                success:function(data)
                {   
                    showInstructions.html(data.test);
                }
            })
        });
    });

</script>
```

Here comes the php  where i send my ajax

```
<?php

require_once('dbconfig.php');

/// Selects all the instructions and shows them in the textarea
if($_POST['status'] == "select") {
    if(isset($_POST['todoId']) && is_numeric($_POST['todoId'])) {
        $id = $_POST['todoId'];

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT instructions FROM todo WHERE id=?");
        $stmt->execute([$id]); 
        $instructions = $stmt->fetch();

        $getInstructions = explode(";",$instructions['instructions']);
        echo json_encode($getInstructions);
    }
    else {
        echo "Something went wrong";
    }
}

if($_POST['status'] == "update") {

    if(isset($_POST['todoId'])) {
        $updateId = $_POST['todoId'];
        $addInstruction = trim($_POST['newInstruction']);
        $array = [
            'test' => "Ny instruktion är tillagd",
            'checkId' => $updateId
        ];

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE todo SET instructions = concat(instructions, ';', :newInstructions) WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->execute( array('newInstructions' => $addInstruction, 'id' => $updateId));

        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your issue. Is it that your textarea value in not resetting to default value or your modal not hiding when you are clicking on save instructton button?

Comment: Wrap the textarea in  form tag

Comment: or you are not able to get textarea value on submit click button which is not posting your textarea value via ajax?

Comment: It's not the same text that is going to server and is being saved but a copy of it so the wording _text won't leaave_ is funny :). You have to reset the value to empty "manually" in the AJAX callback. When a form is submitted traditionally (not AJAX), fields are emptied because the page is reloaded...

Comment: The submit isn't a submit button and it doesn't perform the action of the form element. So you need to programmatically empty the textarea on success

Comment: @Jagruti that's not necessary. 

I guess you want your textarea to be empty after the AJAX post? Try setting its value to '' with ```instructionsText.val('')```

Comment: My issue is when i submit the value, it wont reset to default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the you make a POST request via ajax it doesn't reload the page, no input fields will be cleared. You need to do it manually via JavaScript.

In your example, in the success method of the ajax call that submits the query, you would add:

```
instructionsText.val('');
instructionsText.html('');
```

I used both .val('') and .html('') because of the way textareas handle value. If it was just an `<input>` with `type=text` you only need to clear the value i.e. only use .val('').

You will need to do this for every other input field whose value you want cleared after the request is successfully submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things. First you need to remove textarea value and second you need to close modal popup by js. So you need to make changes in your code as below:

```
submitInstructions.on('click', function (e) {
            var todoId = submitInstructions.attr('data-id'),
                newInstruction = instructionsText.val();
                instructionsText.val(''); // to remove existing value
                $('#testmodal').modal('hide'); //to hide modal popup
                console.log(todoId);
            $.ajax({
                url:"fetchTodoDetails.php",
                method: "POST",
                data:{todoId:todoId, status:"update", newInstruction:newInstruction},
                dataType:"JSON",
                success:function(data)
                {   
                    showInstructions.html(data.test);
                }
            })
        });
```

Hope it helps you.